# In android-NDK build of Native-audio example causes following error

Tags: android, android-ndk

NDK build of native audio causes the following error,does any one have any clue?

```
 jni/native-audio-jni.c:721: error: 'bqPlayerPlay' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:722: error: 'bqPlayerBufferQueue' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:723: error: 'bqPlayerEffectSend' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:724: error: 'bqPlayerMuteSolo' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:725: error: 'bqPlayerVolume' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:729: error: 'fdPlayerObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:732: error: 'fdPlayerPlay' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:733: error: 'fdPlayerSeek' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:734: error: 'fdPlayerMuteSolo' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:735: error: 'fdPlayerVolume' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:739: error: 'uriPlayerObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:742: error: 'uriPlayerPlay' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:743: error: 'uriPlayerSeek' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:744: error: 'uriPlayerMuteSolo' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:745: error: 'uriPlayerVolume' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:749: error: 'recorderObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:752: error: 'recorderRecord' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:753: error: 'recorderBufferQueue' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:757: error: 'outputMixObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:760: error: 'outputMixEnvironmentalReverb' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:764: error: 'engineObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/native-audio-jni.c:767: error: 'engineEngine' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building from the commandline, try

ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-9

Comment: Wow...worked like magic,thanks Sathish,you are a life saver.

Comment: I can only do after 10 mins after you give the answer :P

Comment: @sathish...why has this been voted -1? Any clue?